# Cognos REST API and scheduling schema loading

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am trying to find out more informations about using the REST API in order to create a schedule for schema loading. Right now, I have to reload the particular schemas via my data server connections manually (click on every schema and Load Metadata) and would like to automate this process.

Any pointers will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata of your data warehouse is so in flux that you need to reload the metadata so frequently that you want to automate the process then you need to understand that your data warehouse is in no way ready for use.

So, the question becomes why would you want to frequently reload the metadata of a data source schema?  I'm guessing that you are refreshing the data of your data base and, because your query cache has not expired, you are not seeing the new data.

So the answer is, you probably don't want to do what you think you need to do unless you can convince me otherwise.

Also, if you enter some obvious search terms you will find the Cognos analytics REST api documentation without too much difficulty.

Comment: Many thanks for your input. It's how you said - sometimes there is a change in the database table (structure or a renamed column), but my schemas contain the metadata from the previous version of a table. Once i know which tables in which database changed, i need to hit Load Metadata everytime.
These changes on a database level are regular, so if schema loading could be also scheduled accordingly, that would solve my problem.

Comment: From your question, I thought you were asking about the REST API.  But now you're talking about connecting to a database, not a REST endpoint.  You probably should be using a data server with an appropriate connection string.  In either case, interfaces to data, whether through a data source connection or an API, shouldn't be changing in ways that break things that depend upon them.  Are you sure you aren't using the REST API to do something like read a web page?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input. I am simply looking for one thing: to schedule schema loading, so i dont have to click on Load Metadata everytime there is a change on a database level. I can access the REST API, can delete a Cognos object via it (i set the dispatcher as the endpoint) and looking for an option to somewhow schedule or automate the schema loading. Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: The metadata of a schema should be fairly stable.  If you are adding and dropping columns and tables and changing other metadata so frequently that you want to automate the process of schema loading then you need to understand that your data warehouse is in no REPEAT no way ready for use.  You don't want to do what you think you need to do unless you can convince me otherwise.  Repeating what you've said already not once but twice doesn't really advance anything.